# Terminated nonerror in eclipse java regarding javaw.exe

Tags: java, eclipse

I realize that when eclipse says:

```
<terminated> main [java application] C:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

That the program ran and terminated. My problem is that it doesn't really run, as soon as I hit run it immediately shows this message. The program doesn't run at all. Anyone know how to stop `javaw.exe` from terminating the program immediately?

```
public class main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Twitchbot bot = new Twitchbot();

        bot.setVerbose(true);
        bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", "6667", "oauth:*********************************");
        bot.joinChannel("#donnie64");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have better luck with an answer if you post (some of) the code that may be throwing the error. Regarding your question, you should add a logger somewhere or use a debugger to see where the error jumps.

Comment: kindly post some question ? how anyone will know what's happening with your code , when there is no code to analyze

Comment: That's the thing though, I don't know what part is throwing the error. I'll just post it though @seebiscuit

Comment: public class main {

 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  Twitchbot bot = new Twitchbot();
  bot.setVerbose(true);
  bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", "6667", "oauth:*********************************");
  bot.joinChannel("#donnie64");
  
 }
} @Panther

Comment: The application runs it's just immediately terminated via javaw.exe

Comment: Okay, I created the loop and the problem now is it doesn't even try to go to my chat on my channel. I guess I haven't put something in right or haven't added something I need to access my channel page.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your program **did run**, and It **did exit**, all **without** error or output. It creates a `Twitchbot`, sets it to verbose, connects, joins the channel, then the program ends after that because it has no more instructions, loops, or threads to wait for. The only thing it says is

```
<terminated> main [java application] C:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
```

because that's what Eclipse is supposed to say when a program ends.

If there was an error, it should've printed something in the console in red letters like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at testing.NFATest.main(NFATest.java:45)
```

or whatever exception it threw. (`NullPointerException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, etc)

Comment: I have a set of instructions coded for it but, it won't respond to the twitch chat because it ends immediately. Is there something i was supposed to put to tell it to stand idle until commands are recieved?

Comment: Well, what library is this? You'll have to read the documentations. In simple networking situations like this, you'll need a while loop to call a method repeatedly to accept incoming connections in another thread